Facebook Graph API Problem in authentication with advanced scopes
I'm building a solution that'll require me to authenticate Facebook business accounts and get access to their pages and Instagram handles. And my platform will be used to posts and schedule. Just like Ayrshare. How can I get scopes for :-
instagram_business_content_publish
pages_manage_posts
pages_show_list
publish_video
I tried react
@greatsumini/react-facebook-login
but its not allowing me to add more scopes
<FacebookLogin
      appId={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FACEBOOK_ID as string}
      onSuccess={FacebookLoginOnSuccess}
      onFail={(error) => {
        console.log("Login Failed!", error);
      }}
      onProfileSuccess={FacebookOnProfileSuccess}
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "#4267b2",
        color: "#fff",
        fontSize: "16px",
        padding: "12px 24px",
        border: "none",
        borderRadius: "4px",
      }}
      scope="email,public_profile"
    />

